# How to create xml file with sqlite3 efficiently?

Tags: c, sqlite, libxml2

I am looking for a tool which converts the results of SQL queries into XML format.
For example:

select name, email, phone from MY_TABLE;

the XML will be something like:

```
<Result>
   <name>...</name>
   <email>abc</email>
   <phone>11111</phone>
</Result>
<Result>
   <name>...</name>
   <email>xyz</email>
   <phone>22222</phone>
</Result>
```

BTW, I am using the SQLite3 for DB and libxml2 too.

Comment: SQLite has nothing to do with XML and has no support for returning non-tabular data. You'll have to query the appropriate structure and emit XML as appropriate (the SQLite and libxml documentation should explain how to do the respective operations) - don't worry about "efficiently" until after "working".

Comment: Do you really *have* to do this in C? It can be done in e.g. less than 20 lines of python.